# How to import pop3/imap mails to new server (backup and restore IMAP/POP3 account)?

Tags: email, backup, email-server

I have new Ubuntu server with Dovecot installed, with Roundcube frontend, with root access.

And an inbox on third party service (web hosting + own domain pointed there by setting DNS addresses), without any server access, I just have credentials to Roundcube and IMAP/POP3/SMTP settings. I don't even know which protocol is this mail using (both all allowed).

How can I import all mails from this third party service inbox to the Dovecot?
(i.e. mirror my mails to Dovecot, then point my domain to the new server).

Comment: Similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/605342/migrating-from-any-imap-pop3-server-to-dovecot